# Put a named key before numeric keys in array

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

Need to compare two arrays

Working example

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

Array1 Output:

```
Array ( [a] => green [0] => red [1] => blue )
```

When I do Like this

```
$array1 = array();

while($fetch = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $array1[] = $fetch['color'];
}
```

I get this output:

```
Array ([0] => gren [1] => red [2] blue
```

How do I add the "a" to the array and make the first color be number zero?

This adding the "a" but it gets the zero number

```
array_unshift($array1,"a");
```

LIKE

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => green
```

I want this

```
Array ( [a] => green [0]
```

Comment: Why are you mixing named and numeric keys in the array? That rarely makes sense.

Comment: What does this problem have to do with `array_intersect`?

Comment: My outputs is print_r

Comment: I dont get any hits with array_intersect. I thought it was because I did not caled it "a" and "b"

Comment: `array_intersect` just looks at the values, it doesn't care about the keys.

Comment: `array_intersect_assoc` matches both keys and values.

Comment: With count($result) i get zero results. Same result with array_intersect_assoc or array_intersect

Comment: I get a result: http://ideone.com/GoRZVr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to do this, but here's how:

```
$array1 = array();
while ($fetch = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    if (empty($array1)) {
        $array1['a'] = $fetch['color'];
    } else {
        $array1[] = $fetch['color'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(0 => 'green', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'blue');
$res = array_merge(array('a' => current($arr)), array_slice($arr, 1));
```

Comment: I dont get any hits with array_intersect

Comment: Is it beacuse array_intersect doesnt work to compare numbers?

Comment: You'll have to show what exactly you're doing with `array_intersect`; it seems irrelevant to the question or my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `array_merge` and `array_shift` function:

```
$arr = array(0 => 'green', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'blue');
$new = array_merge(array('a' => array_shift($arr)), $arr);
```

**Demo:** http://codepad.org/osifrZKZ